# Cmake could not find Eigen3 on HPC

Tags: linux, cmake

I met the same error as (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249140/find-package-eigen3-for-cmake) when trying to install fenics-dolfin on the HPC clusters.

According to @Johannes S., simply using `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")`, can solve the issue. But I am not familiar with linux commands. Can someone provide an example of this? Provided that dir of eigen3 is `/usr/include/eigen3`.

Or, Will the adding path in `~/.bashrc` and `sourcing` do the same thing? (But I do not know where the eigen3 locates in HPC since the `cmake` is loaded in the background)

Thanks!

```
CMake Error at /curc/sw/cmake/3.14.1/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Eigen3 (missing: EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR EIGEN3_VERSION_OK)
  (Required is at least version "3.2.90")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /curc/sw/cmake/3.14.1/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAIULRE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindEigen3.cmake:97 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:276 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Btw, no `sudo` commands could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the file `CMakeLists.txt` in your fenics-dolfin source folder, adding a line

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("$ENV{EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

before the line on which the error happens.